# RDLC Report Column Visibility Problem in Group By

Tags: asp.net, reporting, visibility, rdlc

I have an rdlc report in asp.net.
I have a table in it and I am using group by in that table. But the columns which I make Parent Group or child group has Column Visibility Disabled.

[image]

Notes Column is in a group. See its visibility option is disabled.

How can I hide that column on the basis of a criteria as I can do with the Exam Date column that is not in any group.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've concluded that it's not possible to do this.