# Unable to hide Group Column RDLC

Tags: report, rdlc

Before running my report, I give the user options to choose which Columns they would like to see.

I then hide columns by reading and setting boolean parameter for "Column Visibility"

I am able to hide static columns using an expression for "Column Visibility" (Fig 2) as follows:
`= iif(Parameters!MinorVisibility.Value = "true", false,true)`

[image]

When I try to hide my Group Columns, "Column Visibility" is disabled as seen in Fig 1. I tried manually setting each cell's visibility property but then I am left with a blank column as seen in Fig 3.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is to remove this column and re-add it as regular column inside group (to the left of your Date column).

Comment: Any columns added to the left of the dashed line (to the left of Amount) will not have "Column Visibility" option

Comment: if you right-click on your date column and add column to the left of it - then new column should have visibility property. And then remove your Minor Category column. It should work, I had similar problem and it helped.

Comment: I right-click date column > Insert Column > Left and the new column still has the same problem

Comment: I'm at a loss at the moment. This question was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740975/rdlc-report-column-visibility-problem-in-group-by and no solution was found.

Comment: Also, here is the documentation on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251711.aspx

Comment: I ended up loading the rdlc into an xmldocument object , adjusting the size to 0.0001in and loading the report from the xmldocument